# Using transactional Cypher REST endpoint to create indexes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Am I supposed to use a [separate](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-schema-indexes.html) URL to create schema indexes in Neo4j, or should I be able to use transactional Cypher enpoint (`db/data/transaction/commit`) for that as well?

The reason I'm asking this is that I'm getting

`Neo.TransientError.Transaction.DeadlockDetected,LockClient[3] can't wait on resource RWLock[SCHEMA(0), hash=833390523] since => LockClient[3] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[SCHEMA(0), hash=833390523] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- LockClient[2] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[SCHEMA(0), hash=833390523]`

when submitting simple query

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)
```

to an empty database (version 2.3.1). Restarting and recreating Neo4j database doesn't help.

**UPDATE:** after additional investigation I realized that the error is returned only when I send two `CREATE INDEX` commands at the same time in parallel. Running them sequentially works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can use the transactional endpoint to create indexes.

I've run that using [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie) client successfully:

```
http -a neo4j:<mypw> -b -j localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit \
 statements:='[{"statement": "create index on :Person(name)"}]'
```

Be aware that it's not possible to do `create index` operations and mutating stuff (`CREATE`, `MERGE`, `SET`,...) in the same transaction.

Take a look at `data/graph.db/messages.log` to get further insight.

## regarding your update

index operations take locks, so they cannot run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look. It does work sometimes though.

Comment: I tailed `messages.log` - no information is logged regarding my issue.